# How to separate a not-continuous sequence of integers by gaps greater than 10?

Tags: powershell, sequence

In Powershell: How can I separate a sorted not-continuous sequence of integers by gaps greater than 10? For better clarification I set up a quick Excel sheet which explains pretty much everything:

[image]

My current awkward code

```
$input = @(108,109,111,112,276,278,282,300,515,516,517,523,527,
           552,553,554,555,556,557,558,559,561,562,563,706)

$output = @()
for($i=0; $i -lt $input.count; $i++){    
  if ($input[$i] -le ($input[$i+1])-10 ) {
   $output += $input[$i]
  }
}
$output += $input[$input.count-1]
```

Correct example output is `112,282,300,527,563,706`

**Question:** Can this be done in a simpler way? I have a feeling that I overcomplicate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got this:

```
$array = @(108,109,111,112,276,278,282,300,515,516,517,523,527,552,553,554,555,556,557,558,559,561,562,563,706)
0..($array.count -2) | foreach { @($array[$_]) -lt $array[$_ + 1] - 10 }

112
282
300
527
563
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Not sure if it is any prettier, but it's "more powershell".

Be aware that `$input` is a bad variable name as it is already in use by powershell to access the whole pipeline-flow as an enumerator.

```
$arr = @(108,109,111,112,276,278,282,300,515,516,517,523,527,552,553,554,555,556,557,558,559,561,562,563,706)

$arr | ForEach-Object -Begin { $last = $arr[0] } -Process {    
    if(($_ - $last) -gt 10) {
        $last
    }

    $last = $_
} -End { $arr[-1] }
```

Output:

```
112
282
300
527
563
706
```

Or:

```
$arr = @(108,109,111,112,276,278,282,300,515,516,517,523,527,552,553,554,555,556,557,558,559,561,562,563,706)

$arr | ForEach-Object -Begin { $last = $arr[0] } -Process {    
    if(($_ - $last) -gt 10) {
        $last

        if($_ -eq $arr[-1]) {
            $_
        }
    }

    $last = $_
}
```